# Updating `stellar.toml` contents

Tags: stellar.toml

The Set Options endpoint simply specifies the url for the stellar.toml file. The contents of which can change -- so how does the network validate/checkpoint the configuration content?

Additionally, if I want to make changes to the configuration do I need to update the served stellar.toml along with the high-security Set Options call?

It appears as if the verification process is currently happening on the explorer level when you register your domain with stellar.expert

If anyone can shed more light on stellar.toml verification and update process it would be much appreciated.